# How to migrate scripts written in Google sheets to MS Excel macros in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets

I wrote a script in Google app script to search a value in a sheet and update the row as per user entered values.It works fine with google sheets.But when I downloaded the document as an excel file, I expected the script to be even downloaded and converted to VBA macro, but that is not happening and since I don't have any experience with writing VBA scripts, is there any tol that can be used to translate the .gs to the VBA.
The following is the function if that helps:

```
function test() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  sheet2.getRange('B5:B7').activate();
  var idForSearch = sheet2.getRange("B5").getValue();
  var data = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var rownumber;
  for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
    if(data[i][0] == idForSearch){ //[0] because column A
      Logger.log((i+1))
      rownumber= i+1;
    }
  }
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1'), true);  
  spreadsheet.getRange('A'+rownumber+':'+'C'+rownumber).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Sheet2!B5:B7').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, true);
};
```

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: would you like to transpose the range `'A'+rownumber+':'+'C'+rownumber` to column `B5:B7`?

Comment: i want to transpose the data entered in B5:B7 (say by a user) and paste it on the row A<rownumber>:C<rownumber> in Sheet1 - which can be thought of as a database with all possible values of id . I have to find the row in which records for the id exists and then update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please test the next code. I do not have your data to be processed and I made it only theoretically, without testing...

```
Private Sub testConvert()
 Dim actWork As Workbook, sheet1 As Worksheet, sheet2 As Worksheet
 Dim data As Variant, i As Long, rownumber As Long, rng As Range

 Set actWork = ActiveWorkbook
 Set sheet1 = actWork.Sheets("Sheet1")
 Set sheet2 = actWork.Sheets("Sheet2")
 actWork.Activate
   idForSearch = shee2.Range("B5").Value
   data = sheet1.Range("B5:B7").Value 'not necessary to be activated

   For i = 1 To UBound(data) 'in VBA such an array (created from a range) is 1 based...
        If UCase(data(i,1)) = UCase(idForSearch) Then 'VBA is case sensitive
            WriteLog i 'you must have a function ('WriteLog') able to do it...
            rownumber = i
            'if you have only one occurrence, it is good to exit the loop to save time (not for this specific case of 3 times):
            Exit For
            'If many occurrences may be, you just comment the line above...
        End If
   Next i
   sheet1.Activate 'not necessary
   Set rng = sheet1.Range("A" & rownumber & ":" & "C" & rownumber).Select
   sheet2.Range("B5:B7").Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rng.Value)
End Sub
```

The last to code rows transpose the horizontal range of `sheet1` on column range of `sheet2`...

I can help you in function `WriteLog` creation, if you tell me some more details: What type of log must it be (a text file), on that path to be created, found etc. Do you want to add, append the `i` value, or would you like to rewrite the existing one if any value already has been recorded?

Comment: I just want to find if any row with the id entered in B5 cell (of Sheet2) exists in Sheet 1 and if it exists, then I should be able to overwrite the contents of the columns in that row by using transpose copy

Comment: I understood that from your code, but should it be there only one occurrence? Did you test the above code? If there are more occurrences the code must be updated, but I need to understand the context...

Comment: No, I am not expecting multiple matches, so only one match should be fine as in your answer, (the column A in Sheet1 will have unique IDs ). I tested your code, but I am getting a Subscript out of range at data(i)

Comment: Sorry, please check the updated code. I just replaced `data(i)` with `data(i,1)`. In VBA there are two array types. When it comes from a range VBA uses (array) rows and columns. Even if only one column is involved, you must use it...

Comment: Yes, thanks for the update, I figured that was the issue, it's working fine now , thanks

Comment: Welcome! Do you know how to create a Log Function in VBA? I asked something about its context in case you do not know how to build it...

Comment: No, I am pretty much a novice in VBA, so  I am not even sure what you mean by a log function in this context. However, the transpose copy does the job for me in my use case.

Comment: @soumitra goswami: Well, I must confess that my skills in Google script are the same as yours in VBA... Knowing VBScript and some JScript, I thought I understood your code, but I did that only intuitive. I observed `Logger.log((i+1))` in the loop and I presumed that you need to log the iteration variable...

Comment: oh ok, its not that important. I just added it for debugging purpose, there is no need to have that in the VBA script.

Comment: @soumitra goswami: OK. In such a situation it is good to know that you can use `Debug.Print i + 1` and open Immediate Window using `Ctrl + G` in VBE, to see the result...